# css href attribute using content

Tags: css, html

I am not sure how it works. I know it selects the `href` attribute but why it adds it again using content

```
a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

Comment: It does it because that's what the author of that CSS *told it to do*. This type of CSS is usually used in, for example, a print stylesheet in order that someone reading the hardcopy print-out can see the relevant URLs or, in-browser, so that a user can see where they'll be taken by clicking the link (unless it's obfuscated by an URL shortening service).

Comment: when you post this question why it is appearing??

Answer (score 4):

All it is doing is showing your href attribute in brackets after the text within your link:

consider the following link

```
<a href="test-link.html">this is a test</a>
```

The usual text in this link would be

```
this is a test
```

but with your style applied it will be

```
this is a test (test-link.html)
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n58G7/)